# Cursor disappears when using Messagebox in OnValidating

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a custom textbox I'm doing validation for by overriding the `OnValidating` method. As part of the validation I'm using a message box to give the user feedback.

After the messagebox shows, I set `e.Cancel = true`. This works, but the textbox no longer has the cursor. It has the focus and if you type in the control, it's still working, but the cursor is never displayed. Even if you click in the textbox the cursor is no longer displayed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
  public class txtExample:TextBox
{
    protected override void OnValidating(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SomeValidationCode() == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Validatioon Failed");
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }
        base.OnValidating(e);
    }
    private bool SomeValidationCode()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting the focus?  You are likely to get better responses if you show your code (in particular, if you can shrink your code down to a [mcve] of what you are talking about)

Comment: I have tried using this.Focus() and this.Select(). Im having trouble adding a code snipit. to reproduce popping up a MessageBox with MessageBox.Show and returning e.Cancel = true will do it.

Comment: Im having an issue getting code into the page. All you have to do to reproduce this is call a messagebox from within an overridden OnValidating method.

Answer (score 0):

I can get the behavior I think you want by setting the Selection position this way (right after `e.Cancel = true;`):

```
SelectionStart = this.TextLength;
SelectionLength = 0;
```

You might also want to reverse those values (to select the entire field after a validation failure)

Comment: I tried that and setting the focus. I added a call to the base OnValidating in the if conditional and that seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: I found the position of the base call odd, but I just took your code and set the Selection properties and seemed to get the behavior you wanted.  Glad you fixed your issue

Answer (score 0):

My code was missing a call to the base.OnValidating this seems to have been the cause of the issue.